# Question on export of values to excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel files. Testing , Testing 2.

Testing file values:

[image: Testing.xlsx It has two column key and value]

Testing file has two column, key and value . For each value in column A there is a corresponding value in column B

The second file is testing2.xlsx
with one column Keys

```
Keys                    
10  
11,11.1,11.2    
15  
20
```

I want to map the values in Keys column of testing2.xlsx file to value column of Testing file. I am able to do map the values, but in the output I am not able to put the values as comma separated for keys 11,11.1,11.2. I have to write this output to an excel file.

The output should look like

[image: the desired output]

But what I am getting is :

[image: Output that I am getting]

Can anybody help me in getting the values separated by comma instead of in different rows,.
My code  below:

```
import xlrd                  
import openpyxl

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"Testing.xlsx") # taking handle of testing file            
new_dict={}

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

col_a = sheet.col_values(0, 1)    #taking column value of first column of Testing.xlsx

col_b = sheet.col_values(1, 1)    ##taking column value of second column of Testing.xlsx

my_dict = {a : b for a, b in zip(col_a, col_b)}      # creating a dictionary for column values of Testing file


# Testing2 file 
workbook2 = xlrd.open_workbook(r"Testing2.xlsx")    
sheet_test2=workbook2.sheet_by_index(0)

col_a_test=sheet_test2.col_values(0,1)
#print(col_a_test)
mapping_val=[]
for val in col_a_test:     # separating the column values which are separated by , and storing them in list

    val=str(val).split(',')
    mapping_val.extend(val)
# mapping the values of mapping_val ( key of testing 2 sheet to values of testing sheet )
for vals in mapping_val:     
    if float(vals) in my_dict:              

        new_dict[vals]=my_dict.get(float(vals))

# printing the values to testing2 file                  
myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook('Final.xlsx')                   
worksheet= myworkbook['Sheet1']                                    
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(new_dict.items(), start=1):                    
    cellref=worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2)                          
    cellref_1=worksheet.cell(row=i, column=3)                   
    cellref.value=k                                             
    cellref_1.value=v                                           


myworkbook.save('Final.xlsx')
```

Comment: Instead of images, can you include in your question your input and output tables as text?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel   Is it visible now?